# Front channel URL not being called for Angular 15 MSAL.js v3 when end session endpoint called

Tags: angular, msal.js, angular15

I am having a problem with my front channel url being called from logout.  It works in edge, but not in chrome.  We have several applications that this works for.  The only one that is not logging out is one that uses MSAL.js v3.  Any suggestions?

Scenario: in Chrome

- Sign into App1 https://app1.com - .NET application - front channel url = https://app1.com/signout-oidc
- Sign into App2 https://app2.com - Angular 15 app using MSAL v3 - https://app2.com/logout
- Signout from App2
- Redirects to end_session endpoint
  *Redirect to https://.b2clogin.com/.onmicrosoft.com//oauth2/v2.0/logout
- https://app1.com/signout-oidc is called
- No call to https://app2.com/logout

Looking at just the login for the Angular application, I can see the session cookie that Azure b2c uses to keep track of the session in edge, but there is no cookie for session in chrome.